# java - Interesting issue with doubles

Tags: java, double

I am solving a Codeforces problem, and i ran into an interesting situation with doubles. When i `add(d) to a HashSet` the **output is different** from the output generated when i `add(0.0)` , although the value of `d` must be `0.0` since condition `d == 0.0` must be true at the add operation. Why?

```
HashSet<Double> equations;

...

double d = (double)(y-y0)/(x-x0);
if(y == y0 && d == 0.0) {
    equations.add(0.0); // if add(d) the output is different
}
```

**Problem link:** http://codeforces.com/contest/514/problem/B

**Code:**

```
    int n;
    int c=0;
    int x0,y0;
    HashSet<Double> equations;

    Seqreader read = new Seqreader(" ");
    n=read.nextInt();
    x0 = read.nextInt();
    y0 = read.nextInt();
    equations = new HashSet<Double>();

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int x = read.nextInt();
        int y = read.nextInt();
        if (x == x0) {
            equations.add(20000.0);
        }else {
            double d = (double)(y-y0)/(x-x0);
            if(y == y0 && d == 0.0) {
                equations.add(0.0); // if add(d) output is different
            }
            else
                equations.add(d); // != 0
        }
    }
    System.out.println(equations.size());
```

Comment: What output? And how is the output different?

Comment: `*output is different* // what is it ?`

Comment: when `add(d) -> equations.size() = 37` when `add(0.0) -> equations.size() = 36`

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] ? I might have ideas but need to test it first

Comment: So what is output when you put add(d) instead add(0.0) ?

Comment: I cannot download the input from codeforces, sorry. The test fails for huge input, and its not shown entirely. I do not think it has anything to do with the Seqreader, i have been using it for a while to solve problems at codeforces. However, i can paste is as well if you wish.

Comment: @FilipRistic i have already mentioned it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-0.0 == 0.0, but Double.valueOf(-0.0) does not equal Double.valueOf(0.0).

In your first case, when calling equations.add(d), one time it is adding 0.0, and another it is adding -0.0, which adds two different Double values. In your second case, when you are calling equations.add(0.0) it is adding the same Double value twice.

A small test for this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    double pos = 0.0;
    System.out.println("" + (pos == 0.0)); // true
    double neg = -0.0;
    System.out.println("" + (neg == 0.0)); // true
    System.out.println("" + (neg == pos)); // true
    HashSet<Double> set = new HashSet<Double>();
    set.add(pos);
    set.add(neg);
    System.out.println("" + set.size()); // 2
}
```